# How to override  ad_adapi() in custom module

Tags: 7

Currently, in my custom module that depends from the [Advertisement](http://drupal.org/project/ad) module, I have permissions case, and I want to add `statics_increament` in my custom module.

How can I override `ad_adapi()`?

Answer (score 0):

As the Advertisement module invokes that hook using `module_invoke_all('adapi', 'permissions')`, and it doesn't use `drupal_alter('adapi')`, your module could override that implementation of `hook_adapi()` using code similar to the following one. (I assume the short name of your custom module is "custom_module"; change it to the short name you are using for your module.)

```
function custom_module_adapi($op, $node = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'permissions':
      return array(
        'access statistics' => TRUE,
        'access click history' => TRUE,
        'access activity log' => TRUE,
        'set status as pending' => FALSE,
        'set status as denied' => FALSE,
        'set status from pending to approved' => FALSE,
        'set status from pending to denied' => FALSE,
        'set status from approved to active' => TRUE,
        'set status from approved to offline' => TRUE,
        'set status from active to offline' => TRUE,
        'set status from active to expired' => FALSE,
        'set status from offline to active' => TRUE,
        'set status from offline to expired' => FALSE,
        // Add your permissions.
      );
      break;
  }
}

function custom_module_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'adapi') {
    // Move custom_module_module_adapi() to the end of the list. module_implements()
    // iterates through $implementations with a foreach loop which PHP iterates
    // in the order that the items were added, so to move an item to the end of
    // the array, we remove it and then add it.
    $group = $implementations['custom_module'];
    unset($implementations['custom_module']);
    $implementations['custom_module'] = $group;
  }
}
```

- `custom_module_adapi()` is completely overriding the values returned from `ad_adapi()`; for this reason, it cannot simply add the extra values it needs.
- The code I wrote is a kind of hack; the correct way would be for the Advertisement module to use `drupal_alter()` to allow third-party modules to override the values set from other modules. The code I wrote works, but you need to keep update the code for `custom_module_adapi()` with the code used in `ad_adapi()`, in the case it is changes.
- Only the branch 7.x-1 has `ad_adapi()`; the branch 7.x-2 doesn't have that function anymore. If you are planning to use that branch, the code for your custom module should be changed.